# HTML structure of an email template

Tags: html, css, email

I haven't coded any email/newsletter myself for years, just wondering what are the rules/good practices nowadays:

1. should the template have the same structure as a web page meaning starting with the `<html>` tag?
2. if not should the root element be `<body>`?
3. what about `<!doctype html>` ?
4. is the `<header>` useful since css should be inline and no JavaScript?
5. do we have the choice anyway about the root element, like if I just want to send a `<table>` will it work?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid this is awfully broad. What are good practices? If you want a lowest common denominator that will work on all email clients available, then there are so many html features you can't use because some client doesn't support them properly, you'd be better off sending plain text emails.

Answer (score 0):

HTML emails are regular HTML 4.0 documents as they were 10 years ago, nothing changed there.
If you want to develop basic emails , you can continue the same way as you have learned it years ago.

But if you want to develop responsive templates, you almost have to forget everything you have learned and start again. 
Pick a framework like ink or email blueprints (there are also many other)  and read some tutorials to understand how Gmail and smartphone clients work. Again,  zurb provides a lot of interesting and useful information.

After that it is only about testing and making compromises about the design and functionality on different screens in different apps.

Some email marketing providers offer free templates, mail chimp is one of them, (I think.)